# How do I get the text of an XML document when the node's attribute is equal to a certain value?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

So I have an XML document, which contains something like this:

```
<forecast>
        <area aac="NSW_FA001" description="New South Wales" type="region">
            <forecast-period start-time-local="2020-04-13T04:30:05+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-13T04:30:05+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-12T18:30:05Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-12T18:30:05Z">
                <text type="synoptic_situation">A high pressure system over the Bight is extending a ridge across the region, and is expected to slowly move east in coming days to be over the Tasman Sea by Tuesday. This pattern is expected to bring settled conditions to New South Wales for the first half of this week. The next cold front and low pressure trough is forecast to cross the state on Thursday and Friday.</text>
                <text type="warning_summary_footer">Details of warnings are available on the Bureau's website www.bom.gov.au, by telephone 1300-659-218* or through some TV and radio broadcasts.</text>
                <text type="product_footer">* Calls to 1300 numbers cost around 27.5c incl. GST, higher from mobiles or public phones.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="0" start-time-local="2020-04-13T05:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-14T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-12T19:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-13T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">Dry and sunny. Patchy light morning frost about the southern and central ranges and slopes. Patchy morning fog in the east, mainly about the slopes and ranges. Daytime temperatures below average. Light and variable winds.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2020-04-14T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-15T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-13T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-14T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">Dry and sunny. Areas of morning fog in the east. Daytime temperatures near average for most areas. Light and variable winds.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="2" start-time-local="2020-04-15T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-16T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-14T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-15T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">Dry and mostly sunny. Areas of morning fog in the east. Daytime temperatures slightly above average for most areas, particularly the far west. North to northwesterly winds, tending easterly in the northeast.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="3" start-time-local="2020-04-16T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-17T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-15T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-16T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">The chance of a shower across the far south. Dry and partly cloudy elsewhere. Areas of morning fog in the east. Daytime temperatures above average, particularly across the far west. Northwesterly winds, fresh along the southern ranges. A southwesterly change extending across the southern inland during the day.</text>
            </forecast-period>
        </area>
    </forecast>
```

I would like to extract the text where the text type="synoptic_situation", so I would be able to get the text:
"A high pressure system over the Bight is extending a ridge across the region, ..."

I have tried

```
<xsl:variable name = "date" select="product/forecast/area/forecast-period" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$date/text[type='synoptic_situation']/text()" />
```

but it does not seem to work.. is there a way I can grab the text if the text type = "synoptic_situation"? cheers!

Comment: Please show minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT and the output or error you get, together with details on how exactly you use XSLT.

Comment: There is no `product` in the XML you posted.

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the full XML, I didn't want to clog up the question too much.. my mistake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates) - and the predicate needs to reference an **attribute**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="forecast/area/forecast-period/text[@type='synoptic_situation']"/>
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason there is no output.. is there something I need to do for it to print out the text? For additional info, I am using Saxon HE to transform my XML into a html file.

Comment: You can see it working here (with the input as shown in your question): https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhDDze

Comment: Nevermind, you're correct it is working. I forgot to add the "product" as the XML I posted above was incomplete.. my mistake! Thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks for your help & for the link to that useful tool!